# How to set environment variables of the shell resulting from the vim :sh command

Tags: vim

I often use `:sh` in Vim to get out to a shell and perform some action, then I `$ exit` to return back to my Vim session. The issue is that sometimes I come back to a tab and I forget if I have exited from a Vim session or not, and typing `$ exit` will close the tab or SSH connection if I guess wrong and I'm not in a subshell from Vim. I would like to be able to set some special environment variables of the shell when opening a subshell from Vim with `:sh`. Is there a way to do this?

I was thinking something like `:sh ENVVAR="vim is open!"` I could then display ENVVAR in my PS1 if the variable is set, but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `let` to set an environment variable. Just prepend the name of the variable with `$`.

```
:let $ENVVAR = 'vim is open!'
:sh
$ echo $ENVAR
vim is open!
```

See `:help :let-environment`. Of course, you can put the `let` command in your vimrc. In addition, vim sets some environment variables on its own, which you could also query from your shell:

```
:sh
$ env | grep VIM
VIMRUNTIME=/usr/share/vim/vim81
VIM=/usr/share/vim
MYVIMRC=/home/user/.vimrc
```

Comment: Fantastic! I was able to add
nnoremap <C-D> :let $VIMFILE = @% \| :sh<CR>
to my .vimrc and now I can change my $PS1 to show which file I was editing when I went out to the shell!

Comment: This helped me update the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable in an already running vim process in a long-running tmux session.  This allowed me to keep my current Vim session and update the ssh-agent socket file that changes daily.  Yes, I know about vim sessions, but sometimes that doesn't work well with some plugins and I tend to avoid it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're running on Linux or macOS (or something reasonably similar), you can get the parent process name by doing this:

```
ps -p $PPID -o comm=
```

So you could add something to your shell configuration like this:

```
IN_VIM=$(ps -p $PPID -o comm= | grep -qsE '[gm]?vim' && echo 1)
```

and then do something depending on whether `$IN_VIM` is non-empty.